# Android Socket.IO - Connect to a Nodejs server from an android app (works on a browser)?

Tags: android, node.js, sockets

I have a NodeJs server and I want to connect it with my Andoird native app thru socket.io.
When I use the domain from demo (demo: http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) it works, and the socket is connected

```
private Socket mSocket;
{
   try {
       mSocket = IO.socket("http://chat.socket.io");
   } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
}



mSocket.connect();
```

However, when I try my own server address the socket does not connect

```
private Socket mSocket;
{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://ec2-23-23-240-76....:7003/");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
}

mSocket.connect();
```

Someone have any idea why?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to examine socket.io logs whether client hits server endpoint

DEBUG=* node server_chat_app_code.js